# Gravity Forms Repeater Add-On » JQuery Error when click on add button

Tags: wordpress, repeater, gravity-forms-plugin

I’m using repeater for a single line text. The repeater appears correct on the form, but when I click on ‘+’ button to add more text box then it shows `TypeError: gfRepeater_repeaters[e] is undefined error` in the console and the new field is not added. I tried debugging for the issue but no luck.

I’m using: 
WordPress version 4.9.5, 
Gravity Forms version 2.2.6, 
Gravity Forms Repeater Add-On version 1.0.9

I do have idea that official support for this plugin is no more active and on the plugin site it is given that the plugin is tested and working for WordPress version 4.4.15 but still looking for any fix for the issue.

The form having issue opens in a fancybox pop-up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm Kodie, the creator of the Gravity Forms Repeater Add-On. As you've mentioned, support for the plugin is no longer happening and fixing bugs such as this as well as making sure the plugin works correctly with the latest versions of both WordPress and Gravity Forms would require some work. I have been pointing people to [Gravity Forms Nested Forms by Gravity Wiz](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/?ref=145)* instead.

*Disclaimer: Affiliate link